# Bulma CSS - 'nav-toggle' not working

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, nav, bulma

When clicking on the navbar menu in mobile responsive mode, the menu will sometimes refrain from opening.

It was working quite well in localhost but I noticed that when deployed to a server, the menu would not open.  Also noticed a difference in functionality between browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work with a hack to the bulma.js jQuery file.

Instead of:

```
    $toggle.click(function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
       $menu.toggleClass('is-active');
    });
```

You can ensure the click function will work with this:

```
    $toggle.click(function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
       $menu.toggleClass('is-active');
       $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
       $menu.toggleClass('is-active');
    });
```